# CASE condition and SUM() common table expressions or Group By

Tags: sql, sum, sql-order-by, case, common-table-expression

Hope some can help ? I have a 3rd party software were i can do custom sql querys but not able to change any of the database. Struggling to get the result i would like.

Do I use GROUP BY or CTE to get the result i need?

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT  tblTicketsSummary.fldDateScheduled AS [Scheduled], 
tblTicketsRow.fldStartTime  AS [TIME], tblTicketsRow.fldPs AS 
[s],tblTicketsRow.fldPrice AS PR, 
tblTicketsSummary.fldFirstName+' '+tblTicketsSummary.fldLastName 
AS [Client], ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID ORDER BY 
tblTicketsRow.fldTicketID) AS C, tblTicketsSummary.fldDateClosed 
AS [Date Closed],
 CASE WHEN tblTicketsRow.fldPs ='p' THEN tblTicketsRow.fldPrice  
ELSE £0.00 END AS Product,  
CASE WHEN tblTicketsRow.fldPs ='s' THEN tblTicketsRow.fldPrice  
ELSE £0.00 END AS Services, 
FROM tblTicketsSummary INNER JOIN 
tblTicketsRow ON tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID = tblTicketsRow.fldTicketID
 WHERE (fldDateVoided IS NULL) AND (NOT(fldDateClosed IS NULL)) 
GetUserDate('AND','fldDateClosed','') AND tblTicketsRow.fldEmployeeName ='Tina Young' 
 AND tblTicketsSummary.fldTotal >1 )
SELECT * FROM  CTE   ORDER BY   Scheduled ASC,  TIME ASC
```

This give me the result below . I have removed Where c=1 in the last select which i will put back in the final query which give me the first result by time which is what i want. The bit i am struggling with is. I would like to add the prices of all products together and the prices of all service together to give a total of products and services sold. Then a grand total of services and product together in the final query .

```
Scheduled   TIME s   PR      Client   C Date Closed Product  Services  Total
17/07/2020 17:00 S £10.00 Ben Preston 1 17/07/2020  £0.00    £10.00     s+p
17/07/2020 17:45 S £1.00  Ben Preston 2 17/07/2020  £0.00    £1.00      s+p
17/07/2020       P £19.00 Ben Preston 3 17/07/2020  £19.00   £0.00      s+p
17/07/2020       P £10.00 Ben Preston 4 17/07/2020  £10.00   £0.00      s+p
```

The Result i  would like is  below.  The final part of the query is as below.  I am only able to custom query's in the 3rd party software.

```
 SELECT * FROM  CTE  WHERE c=1 ORDER BY   Scheduled ASC,  TIME ASC 


Scheduled  TIME   Client       C   Date Closed  Product Services   Total
17/07/2020 17:00 Ben Preston   1   17/07/2020   £29.00   £11.00    £40.00
```

I hope I have formatted this right for people to understand. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you simply need to add two *Group Sums* to your existing CTE and then add them in your final Select:

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT  tblTicketsSummary.fldDateScheduled AS [Scheduled], 
   tblTicketsRow.fldStartTime  AS [TIME], 
   tblTicketsRow.fldPs AS [s],tblTicketsRow.fldPrice AS PR, 
   tblTicketsSummary.fldFirstName+' '+tblTicketsSummary.fldLastName AS [Client], 
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID
         ORDER BY tblTicketsRow.fldStartTime) AS C, 
   tblTicketsSummary.fldDateClosed AS [Date Closed],
   
   SUM(CASE WHEN tblTicketsRow.fldPs ='p' THEN tblTicketsRow.fldPrice ELSE £0.00 END)
   OVER (PARTITION BY tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID) AS Product,  
   
   SUM(CASE WHEN tblTicketsRow.fldPs ='s' THEN tblTicketsRow.fldPrice ELSE £0.00 END)
   OVER (PARTITION BY tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID) AS Services
FROM tblTicketsSummary
INNER JOIN tblTicketsRow
ON tblTicketsSummary.fldTicketID = tblTicketsRow.fldTicketID
WHERE (fldDateVoided IS NULL) AND (NOT(fldDateClosed IS NULL)) 
--GetUserDate('AND','fldDateClosed','') AND tblTicketsRow.fldEmployeeName ='Tina Young' 
 AND tblTicketsSummary.fldTotal >1 )
SELECT cte.*,
   Product + Services as total
FROM  CTE
WHERE C = 1
ORDER BY   Scheduled ASC,  TIME ASC;
```

Btw, the `ORDER BY tblTicketsRow.fldTicketID` on your ROW_NUMBER is not based on a unique column, thus the order of rows is not guaranteed. You probably want `order by tblTicketsRow.fldStartTime` instead.

Comment: You might also be able to get your expected result using plain aggregation...

Comment: Hi Dnoeth Thank you for that but i am unsure were to enter the code you have provide. I am a web designed no a database expert. Been trying to work this out for weeks. Could i ask you to paste the code into the query please. Thank you

Comment: Thank you . Getting 2 syntax errors near 'tlbTicketsSummaryINNER' and near CTEWHERE . Any ideas . Again thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems the 3rd party software removes all line breaks and now there's no whitespace between `tlbTicketsSummary` and `INNER`. Simply add a space at the end of each line

Comment: Thank you so much !! Virtual beer from me to you.

Comment: Dnoeth just one other thing to make it read easier i what to remove ELSE £0.00 on products and service (leave the row blank) but when i do that the total field is blank . How can i do this please cheers. Thank you

Comment: Keep it. If you omit ELSE it defaults to NULL, which might look like blank. And calculations involvibg NULs result in NULL.

Comment: Is there any way round this or do i have to leave £0.00 in ? Can i use Case When in the product + services AS Total

Comment: Ok Think i solved it.  Changed Product + Services As Total to ISNULL(Product, 0) + ISNULL(Services,0) AS Total . Thanks again

Comment: Well, this just moves the `0` to a different place (COALESCE is a shortcut for CASE)

Comment: Ok  so what you are saying i have to leave ELSE £0..00  END in. the reason i wanted to remove it is the report is long and a lot  easier to read when  £0.00 is removed. But if a can not remove i will leave in no worries thank again .

Comment: `ELSE £0.00 END` can be written as `ELSE 0 END`, but I think you want to remove the zeroes for Product/Services from the final result and then ISNULL (or Standard SQL COALESCE) is the right way.